Baseline Profile build fails with `The value for property 'experimentalProperties' is final and cannot be changed any further.`
Adding baseline profile to our project and build fails with the following exception.
Build failure logs:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The value for property 'experimentalProperties' is final and cannot be changed any further.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.ValueState$FinalizedValue.beforeMutate(ValueState.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.assertCanMutate(AbstractProperty.java:371)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultMapProperty.addExplicitCollector(DefaultMapProperty.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultMapProperty.access$600(DefaultMapProperty.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultMapProperty$Configurer.addCollector(DefaultMapProperty.java:710)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultMapProperty$Configurer.put(DefaultMapProperty.java:716)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultMapProperty.put(DefaultMapProperty.java:187)
    at androidx.baselineprofile.gradle.consumer.BaselineProfileConsumerAgpPlugin.onVariants(BaselineProfileConsumerPlugin.kt:207)
    at androidx.baselineprofile.gradle.utils.AgpPlugin$configureWithAndroidPlugin$4$3.invoke(AgpPlugin.kt:176)
    at androidx.baselineprofile.gradle.utils.AgpPlugin$configureWithAndroidPlugin$4$3.invoke(AgpPlugin.kt:174)
    at com.android.build.api.extension.impl.AndroidComponentsExtensionImpl$onVariants$1.execute(AndroidComponentsExtensionImpl.kt:75)
    at com.android.build.api.extension.impl.AndroidComponentsExtensionImpl$onVariants$1.execute(AndroidComponentsExtensionImpl.kt:74)
    at com.android.build.api.extension.impl.OperationsRegistrar.executeOperations(OperationsRegistrar.kt:60)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$createVariantsFromCombination$8.invoke(VariantManager.kt:978)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$createVariantsFromCombination$8.invoke(VariantManager.kt:975)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.computeVariants(VariantManager.kt:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariants(VariantManager.kt:189)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.kt:715)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$createTasks$2$1.call(BasePlugin.kt:599)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.NoOpAnalyticsConfiguratorService.recordBlock(NoOpAnalyticsConfiguratorService.kt:57)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$createTasks$2.accept(BasePlugin.kt:594)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$createTasks$2.accept(BasePlugin.kt:591)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:37)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.CrashReporting$afterEvaluate$1.execute(crash_reporting.kt:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:268)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:272)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:92)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy60.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:247)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1459)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:253)
    ... 146 more

Project setup details:

'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.2'
id 'androidx.baselineprofile' version '1.3.3' apply false
Gradle 8.9

It is a multimodule project.

Had this issue with benchmark plugin 1.3.3, AGP 8.7.3, and gradle 8.11.1.
Try to add this to build.gradle in the app project:
android {

    baselineProfile {
        hideSyntheticBuildTypesInAndroidStudio = false
    }
...


The benchmark plugin has this code:
    override fun onVariants(variant: Variant) {

        // Controls whether Android Studio should see this variant. Variants created by the
        // baseline profile gradle plugin are hidden by default.
        if (
            baselineProfileExtension.hideSyntheticBuildTypesInAndroidStudio &&
                isBaselineProfilePluginCreatedBuildType(variant.buildType)
        ) {
            variant.experimentalProperties.put("androidx.baselineProfile.hideInStudio", true)
        }

Looks like experimentalProperties is locked for modification at this moment.
However, I couldn't reproduce it with the official benchmark sample.
Probably another plugin locked this property, I didn't investigate which one.
